# How to deploy blazor wasm to iis as an application and not as a website

Tags: blazor, blazor-client-side, blazor-webassembly, asp.net-blazor

I've been trying to deploy my blazor wasm that I've published in visual studio to IIS as an application. It works when I change the base href="/app/" but upon navigating to other pages e.g. mywebsite.com/app/counter. When I press F5(refresh) in chrome it displays an iis message that says directory not found. Please help.

Comment: Can you check in IIS if the published project has an icon as application otherwise try to Convert to application from within iis menu.

Comment: Hi Hassan. Already did that. I was able to make it work but when I press F5 to refresh the page. it says directory not found.

Answer (score 1):

Please install URL rewrite module on the server from https://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/url-rewrite. I've had same problem and installing rewrite fixed this issue. Let me know if this does not work for further research.'

Also, if you have given redirection as

```
Navigationmanager.NavigateTo("/counter")
```

Remove '/' and just use counter after you have used /app/ in index.html. It even works if you add an application as a website.

Comment: Hi Ajinkya! Thank you! yes I have already installed the url rewrite module and also removed the prefix "/". but still the same. were you able to deploy your blazor wasm app as App under Default website in IIS?

Comment: Yes I was able to deploy the blazor web assembly app as an application under default website

Comment: I tried and wasnt able to work after i installed the url-rewrite. May I know what steps you did? Thanks

Comment: I published the blazor app to a folder. Then in IIS. I added a application under default website and pointed to the folder where there is web. config. Then I changed the index.html to change the base path. I had installed .net core runtime and URL rewrite module to the server.